# Create list from list items

Tags: list, tcl, var

I am trying to crate a new array/list from an existing list of items. I am wanting to check if the item exist first, if it does not, create it then add a value to it. If it already exist just append a value. I also need a way to get the length of the total.

```
    set Area {23401 23402 23403}
    foreach Item $Area {
      set ElExist [info exist ${Item}lst]
      if {$ElExist == 0} {
        set ${Item}lst {};
        lappend ${Item}lst $TotalRecords
      } else {
        lappend ${Item}lst $TotalRecords
      }
      set CurrentOptinon [llength ${Item}lst]
    }
```

Comment: Uh, it's kind of hard to understand what you're trying to do. Can you put some more information, like some dummy existing variables, and what do you expect to end up with, i.e. what array/lists?

Comment: `lappend` will create a new variable if the var name does not exist. If your intention of checking whether variable exists or not is for something else, you can keep it. Else, you can remove it. But, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was writing that code, I'd do it like this:

```
set Area {23401 23402 23403}
foreach Item $Area {
    upvar 0 ${Item}lst lst
    lappend lst $TotalRecords
    set CurrentOptinon [llength $lst]
}
```

This will behave the same as your code, but it's so much shorter. Here's the tricks in use:

1. `lappend` creates a variable if it didn't already exist.
2. `upvar 0` makes a local *alias* to a variable. So much simpler.
3. The alias removes the need for magic with `llength`, but otherwise you could have done:

   ```
   set CurrentOptinon [llength [set ${Item}lst]]
   ```

   The `$` syntax is in many ways just a short-cut for a call to the single-argument version of `set`, which *reads* the named variable. Except if you write `set` then you can use substitutions in your variable name. As a rule of thumb, if you're extensively using variable names in variables without aliasing, you're probably doing something wrong (unless you really do need the *name*).
4. You're using weird variable names. Much better would be an array.

   ```
   set Area {23401 23402 23403}
   foreach Item $Area {
       lappend lst($Item) $TotalRecords
       set CurrentOptinon [llength $lst($Item)]
   }
   ```

   However, this is likely to require you to change code elsewhere.

Comment: I want to thank you for always being so helpful. You have always been so quick in replying to anything when I need help with any TCL. Question is your E-Mail still donal.k.fellows@manchester.ac.uk? I found this on the TCL community.